# Null Check when interating LinkedList throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I'm coding in Java, and I had to make a LinkedList manually. It is doubly linked, and the tail's next pointer points to null. I'm using this to iterate through the list until I reach the end for a sorting algorithm (bubble sort).

```
Node<?> current = a.getHead();
while (current.getNext() != null) { //this line throw a NullPointerException
         //sorting algorithm
        current = current.getNext();
}
```

Here's the code for getNext() as well:
`Node<?> current = a.getHead();`.
Why is Java throwing a NullPointerException here?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad But I'm asking why java is throwing the exception when I'm checking for that case

Comment: You are not checking if `current` is null. you are checking `current.getNext()` is not null. If you `current` is null then `current.getNext()` will throw `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in line `Node<?> current = a.getHead();`

```
a.getHead(); is returning null.
```

Please check like -

```
while (current != null && current.getNext() != null) {
         //sorting algorithm
        current = current.getNext();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought to check that line. The error is no longer thrown and the sort works.